# MEF - ApiController - IHttpController not resolved

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef

I am new to MEF and played around with MVC and it's working alright. However, when I tried with Web API, external api controllers weren't resolved. Here's my code for the DependencyResolver:

```
public class MefDependencyResolver : System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver,  IDependencyResolver
        {
            private readonly CompositionContainer _container;

            public MefDependencyResolver(CompositionContainer container)
            {
                this._container = container;
            }

            public object GetService(Type serviceType)
            {
                string name = AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType);
                var service = this._container.GetExportedValueOrDefault<object>(name);
                return service;
            }

            public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
            {
                string name = AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType);

                try
                {
                    var service = this._container.GetExportedValues<object>(name);

                    return service;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return new object[] { };
                }
            }

            public System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyScope BeginScope()
            {
                return this;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {}
        }
```

and here's how it was used:

```
var _resolver = new MefDependencyResolver(_container);
System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = _resolver;
```

and here's the external api controller:

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
}
```

but when I visit my site:

```
http://localhost:65232/api/values
```

I got this error:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:65232/api/values'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'values'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

the same container works with my MVC Controller but can't seem to make it work with API controllers.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: To check if it's not rather a routing issue, set a bookmark in your resolver to see if it's hit.

Comment: the resolver was hit, except that it returns null for APi controllers while it is giving instances if it's MVC controllers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two interfaces involved here, both with the same name `IDependencyResolver` hence the confusion. One is for MVC, and one is for Web API.

I solved it like this. I have:

```
public class WebApiDependencyResolver : System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class MvcDependencyResolver : WebApiDependencyResolver, System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
{
    public MvcDependencyResolver(CompositionContainer container)
        : base(container)
    {
    }
}
```

The `MvcDependencyResolver` inherits from the `WebApiDependencyResolver` to avoid code duplication.

Then you need to register the resolver with MVC *and* Web API. So somewhere in your startup code you should have something like this:

```
        var resolver = new MvcDependencyResolver(Container);
        System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver); // install MEF dependency resolver for MVC
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver; // install MEF dependency resolver for Web API
```

Having said all this, I personally wouldn't go with MEF for controller resolution as it introduces a **memory leak** because MEF keeps references to `IDisposable` types and `ApiController` is `IDisposable`.

Comment: ah that makes sense..   with regards to controller resolution and memory leaks, I think i have to reconsider using an IoC like AutoFac or Unity..

Comment: Be aware that ASP.NET 5 is shipping with its own DI framwork. A beta is already out there. You can [read here](http://blog.2mas.xyz/asp-net-5-ioc-and-dependency-injection/) more for example.

Comment: cool! sounds like a better option.. :) seems like this answered my other unanswered question...  many thanks!